# How to configure DNS for a delegated domain?

Tags: dns, nameservers

I am working with a company, developing and managing a web site for them.

I have control over the web servers, but the company is managing DNS for the domain.

Due to their security policy, the web servers are prohibited from issuing outbound email - they won't add the appropriate SPF/DKIM records to DNS to permit this. Instead, I've been told that they will "delegate" the authority of the domain to me by forwarding traffic to nameservers (of my choice), where I am responsible for creating new DNS records to handle that traffic. In these new DNS records, I would add in the appropriate SPF/DKIM records.

It is like I am managing the DNS, but the company still owns it.

The problem is very strange to me, and I am not familiar with the inner workings of nameservers.  Is the relationship of a zone file to a domain name one-to-one?  Would I need a second zone file registered somewhere to hold these new DNS records?  Do I need direct control over the nameservers, or can I work with nameservers provided by a third-party hosting company?

Sorry for the lack of direction - this is new territory for me in a world that I'm already not that well-versed in.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is off-topic since it's not related to programming. It's best suited for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0):

The delegation is a DNS server owning a zone (ie. example.com) and announcing to everyone that a part of this zone (say deleg.example.com) is delegated to another DNS server which can define its own records as long as they are in the deleg.example.com zone.
In your case, it means that you will maintain a subdomain that will hold your NS and SPF/DKIM records. This subdomain behaves in a similar way as the main domain thus you will need a second DNS zone file (and another DNS server).

This is similar to what root servers do with top level domains (they own the com / net / whatever zones) and subdomains sold to companies / people (ie. google.com handles whatever lies in the google.com zone but does not affect the "com" zone).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me (actually). In my case, it seems they want to do the actual domain, not a subdomain, so I would need to recreate all DNS records (A, CNAME, MX, etc), if that makes sense.

About the DNS server and zone file - how are these instantiated, without registering a brand new domain? Can I just put this company's domain name in the zone file, and their forwarding of traffic to the nameservers will just find it?

Comment: If you have to replicate the whole DNS zone, that's a really twisted solution IMHO. Especially if they update their zone, and yours differs. If think that you should ask your contact to send you more information.